# Fetch Username from Lookup-Column using Powershell

Tags: powershell, lookup-column

In my powershell script, I have a method that fetches a username from a sharepoint list.  This works fine - my problem is that field is from a lookup column.  The user chooses the username from a lookup column.

That means that the usernames are returned to my script as strings, but with a `10;#` prepended to the username where the `10` is the id of the item in the lookup's source list (I think).

But I need to have a clean username, without the `10;#` prepended.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "http://yoursite"
$List = $Web.Lists["Listname"]
$Item = $List.Items[0];
$Lookup = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue($Item["YourField"])
$User = $Lookup.LookupValue;
```

Comment: So you would tell me that using the `$Lookup` that way would return the real lookup value instead of the funny return string?  I'll try that out.

Comment: Yes it should. It contains two properties LookupValue and LookupId.

Comment: I'm having trouble with that.  $lookup seems to be fetching null.

Comment: Make sure are refencing correct, list, listitem and field

Comment: Uh, never mind that.  It's supposed to be null when the field is empty...  Thanks!  It works!  I appreciate it a bunch, fellow.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Pardon again, but how can I get that value returned in username format and not display name format?

Comment: Try `$User = $Web.EnsureUser($Lookup.LookupValue.DisplayName);` That will give you a user object with properties like `UserLogin`, `DisplayName`, `Groups`, and `Email`.